# Why bother doing time series split?

Tags: time-series

From informal guides to peer-reviewed papers, I find this advice time and time again: you should always split your time series respecting the order of the events. This would make sure you don't break the temporal properties of the data.

But machine learning models (at least the basic variants) consider the error of every single data point separately, never being aware that there is some data point before that. In other words, there is no concept of time in the models. Therefore, the training algorithm is never going to make use of any temporal ordering (this can be amended with lagged features).

So how does regular random splitting hurt when dealing with time series?

Comment: You are looking at this the wrong way around. Just because the ML algorithms that you are considering do not respect temporal ordering, does not mean leveraging temporal ordering is not a desirable property for ML algorithms to have. 
That said, there are many ML algorithms, in say binary classification, that respect temporal ordering, and use the dependence structure to predict better.

Comment: Thanks @tchakravarty. But I can't see how your points are relevant to the question. I've never said ordering is desirable or undesirable. Also, I'm not really concerned with the many algorithms that somehow respect time ordering. My only concern is with the basic algorithms that do not deal with time, but people still recommended to use special splitting anyway.

Comment: Bergmeir, Hyndman & Koo (2018) [paper on time series cross validation](https://robjhyndman.com/publications/cv-time-series/) could be relevant.

Comment: @igotthepower I am not sure what advice you have received, and in what context. If you are looking to do time series prediction, then there are very few algorithms that do not leverage the time series structure, and therefore, when applying them out of sample, it is necessary to preserve the natural order in the out of sample split. Are you trying to use potentially inappropriate ML algorithms for time series modelling and prediction? I think it would be helpful for you to specify what is the problem you are trying to solve, and what tools you currently believe to be appropriate for that task.

Comment: One important consideration is that you want to see how stable your results are when you have 'recursive' features.  For example, in an AR setup you could use standard train-test split but then you will have an overly optimistic model for when you have to forecast more than 1 period.  This is because you will have to use the last forecasted point as the actual in the next period's forecast which can bring instability to the results.  Testing this can only be done if the test set is ordered in time.

Answer (score 2):

It’s because no one cares to predict yesterday’s weather, stock prices, coronavirus cases, or gamma ray bursts.

When you have a time series, knowing the before and after could help you fill in a missing time period e.g. if you’re missing weather data from the first week of August, perhaps use the last week of July and the second week of August to speculate on what happened.

However, that’s a different task from predicting what will happen tomorrow, where you can’t burn the candle from both ends.

This is different from, for example, a speech recognition classification algorithm (“Did Dave say something about a dog or a cat?”) that has a time series as the input but nothing temporal as the output.